# Hierarchical Navigable Small World Graphs : Expected Number of Steps in a Layer

Tags: search, k-nearest-neighbors, information-retrieval

Paper: [Efficient and robust approximate nearest
neighbor search using Hierarchical Navigable
Small World graphs](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1603/1603.09320.pdf)

In the Search Complexity section, the author estimates that the expected number of steps in a layer is bounded by $1/(1 - exp(-m_{L})$.
It says:

> *There is a fixed probability $p=exp(-m_{L}
> )$ that
> the next node belongs to the upper layer. However, the
> search on the layer always terminates before it reaches the
> element which belongs to the higher layer (otherwise the
> search on the upper layer would have stopped on a different element), so the probability of not reaching the target on s-th step is bounded by $exp(-s· m_{L}
> )$.*

Shouldn't the probability of reaching the target on s-th step be $(1-exp(-m_{L}))^{s} *exp(-m_{L})$ since this would mean we are reaching a node which belongs to higher layer on the (s+1)<sup>th</sup> hop ? If yes, doesn't it defy the bound introduced in the above paragraph ?

Comment: Hello. You can use latex/mathjax on this site. I recommend that you edit your post to format your symbols and equations with it to improve the readability. You can also prepend the quotes with `>` to make it clear it's a quote.

Comment: Thanks @nbro, edited.